# Target an iFrame using Node.js/Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to target an iFrame when using the GUI Workflow builder in AWS Cloudwatch Synthetics?

I've set up the canary to log in to a website and redirect the page which has run successfully, but one of the elements I need to check with Node.js is within an iFrame which isn't being recognised.

This is the iframe code.  It loads from Javascript, but all content is from the same domain:

```
<iframe id="paramsFrame" src="empty.htm" frameborder="0" ppTabId="-1"
                    onload="paramsDocumentLoaded('paramsFrame', true);"></iframe>
```

This is the code I'm using for this section, but it's just returning a timeout error:

```
   await synthetics.executeStep('verifyText', async function() {
    const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('#paramsFrame');
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
    await frame.waitForXPath("//div[@class=\'css7\'][contains(text(),'Specificity')]", { timeout: 30000 });
})
```

This code is trying to target a div with class `css7` found within an iframe with id `paramsFrame`

Edit:  I did a null check on `frame` and it came back as not null, not sure if that is relevant.

I also tried to target an element directly:

`const next = await frame.waitForSelector('.protocol-name-link');`

but I got the error message:

`TimeoutError: waiting for selector .protocol-name-link`

Comment: Could the issue here be that I'm looking for a class rather than an ID?  I've done further checks and `const frame` is not null, so that would suggest it finds the iFrame, I just need to get it to find elements within the iFrame

Comment: You can check HTML content of the frame by using `await frame.content()` method to make sure the iframe is containing desired selector or XPath.

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe is on a different origin (e.g. different domain), you cannot access it through Puppeteer.

You can try to disable some security features of Puppeteer, although this is not advised.

Specifically, you'd probably want to add these `args` to `puppeteer.launch`

```
 --disable-web-security
 --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process
```

Comment: Hi, it is on the same domain in this case.  It is loaded by javascript though, would that be significant?  Everything the JS loads is from the same domain though.  I've updated the main question with iFrame code

Answer (score 0):

I tried running similar code on a website which had a youtube iframe and I didnt need the puppeteer launch args

i.e

```
args: [
  "--disable-web-security",
  "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process",
],
```

But, First I would like to suggest is for the iframe try to confirm it is the same iframe that you need maybe by logging, debugging or even just going on dev console.

And the second is to use full xpath of the element in the frame.

Here is my code which I tried running.

```
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log("open page");

  await page.goto("https://captioncrusher.com/");
  console.log("page opened");

  // use this if you want to wait for all the requests to be done.
  // await page.waitForNetworkIdle();

  const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector("iframe.yt");
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();

  //These both work for me
  const aLink = await frame.waitForXPath("/html/body/div/div/a");
  const classLink = await frame.waitForSelector(".ytp-impression-link");
 
  await browser.close();
```